# THREE.JS text inverted issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

> #### *Please understand that i cannot accurately deliver all the source code.*

[image: That issue]

it printed, inverted up and down
why is it...

---

#### camera type

```
THREE.OrthographicCamera
```

#### part of renderer setting

```js
constructor() {
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            alpha: true,
            depth: false
        });

        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        this.renderer.autoClear = false;
        this.renderer.autoClearColor = true;
        this.renderer.autoClearStencil = true;
        this.renderer.autoClearDepth = true;
}
```

#### part of camera viewport setting

`__cameraViewportNear` is 0.1

`__cameraViewportFar` is 100

```js
    public setCameraViewport(near: number = this.__cameraViewportNear, far: number = this.__cameraViewportFar) {
        this.getCamera().left = 0;
        this.getCamera().right = this.rendererWidth;
        this.getCamera().top = 0;
        this.getCamera().bottom = this.rendererHeight;
        this.getCamera().near = near; 
        this.getCamera().far = far; 
        this.getCamera().updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
```

#### part of creating mesh

```js
    var extrudeSettings = {
        steps: 2,
        depth: 2,
        bevelEnabled: false,
    };

    //xxx2
    let xxx_shape = self.draws().createShape();
    xxx_shape.moveTo( 34, 16.8421);
    xxx_shape.bezierCurveTo( 34, 29.4737, 17, 40, 17, 40 );
    xxx_shape.bezierCurveTo( 17, 40, 0, 29.4737, 0, 16.8421 );
    xxx_shape.bezierCurveTo( 0, 7.54047, 7.61116, 0, 17, 0 );
    xxx_shape.bezierCurveTo( 26.3888, 0, 34, 7.54047, 34, 16.8421);
    xxx_shape.closePath();

    //xxx3
    let xxx_geo = self.draws().createExtrudeGeometry(xxx_shape, extrudeSettings); // equal new three.extrudegeometry
    let xxx_material = self.draws().createMeshBaiscMeterial({color:0x4fff82}); // equal new three.meshBasicMeterial
    let xxx_mesh = self.draws().createMesh(xxx_geo, xxx_material); // equal new THREE.Mesh


    //xxx4
    const xxx_text = self.draws().createTextMesh(); // https://github.com/protectwise/troika/tree/main/packages/troika-three-text
    xxx_text.text = "HeLp1_23";
    xxx_text.fontSize = 24;
    xxx_text.position.z = 1;
    xxx_text.color = 0xff0000;
    xxx_mesh.add(xxx_text);

    //xxx5
    setTimeout(()=>{
        xxx_text.sync(()=>{
            self.events().emit("@render");
        });
    }, 0);
```

Comment: The first thing I would try is to swap values for camera's top and bottom, so they'll be `top = this.rendererHeight`, `bottom = 0` respectively.

Comment: If you can't deliver the source, then create a [`Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This means create something small and deliverable that can reproduce the problem you're seeing. Chances are, when creating the example, you'll see something you misconfigured or missed that will make all the difference.